# CQ/AEM where are functions like 'cq5forms_showMgs()' defined?

Tags: javascript, aem, web-component, sling

I noticed that CQ occasionally uses these javascript *cq5forms* functions and variables. I'm wondering where they are defined and how they work.

Specifically, I want to know where *cq5forms_isEmpty()* is defined. I'm trying to get the built in clientside validation to work, but the JavaScript console keeps giving a reference error that says *cq5forms_isEmpty()* is not defined.

Some other examples of these *cq5forms* function include the *cq5forms_showMgs()* function in *clientvalidation.jsp* for the built in password constraint:

```
...
if(last!=confirm) {
            cq5forms_showMsg(<%
                %>'<%= xssAPI.encodeForJSString(formId) %>',<%
                %>'<%= xssAPI.encodeForJSString(name) %>_confirm',<%
                %>'<%= xssAPI.encodeForJSString(ValidationHelper.getConstraintMessage(resource)) %>');
            return false; 
    }
...
```

And *cq5forms_isArray()* and *cq5forms_regcheck()* gets written out in FieldHelper.java:

```
    public static void writeClientRegexpText(...)
        ...
        out.write(id);
        out.write(";" +
                  "if ( cq5forms_isArray(obj)) { \n" +
                  "for(i=0;i<obj.length;i++) { \n" +
                  "if (!cq5forms_regcheck(obj[i].value, ");
        out.write(regexp);

        out.write(")) { \n" +"cq5forms_showMsg('");
        ...
```

If anyone could point me to where these are defined and how they are suppose to be used it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This javascript functions belong to the cq.forms clientlibrary. 
You can find the js code at the following location in crx
/etc/clientlibs/foundation/form/form.js

Comment: Thanks Thomas! That's exactly what I was looking for. A follow up question, how are these script imported into the project?

Comment: Through the clientlibrary system. Any client side code can be organized in client library folder in AEM. These folder are categorized, can declare or embed depndencies and the system takes care of delivering the required JS and CSS code into the website by just including a reference to the clientlib. See https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/developing/clientlibs.html